# Swift - TabViewController with SwipeViewControler in one of its tabs

Tags: swift, xcode, viewcontroller

Another newbie to swift here. I want my application to have four tabs on the bottom and inside one of the tabs I want to be able to swipe between two 'pager' style tabs.

I have been able to make the four tabs work at the bottom by starting a new tabbed app and adding two additional view controllers.

[image: I want the SwipeView inside of the Home tab]

Then I tried adding a SwipeViewController (https://github.com/fortmarek/SwipeViewController) to one of the tabs and it worked but it overrode the entry point so all I see is the two SwipeView tabs without the TabController tabs on the bottom.

[!I want this inside of the Home tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbmRn.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbmRn.jpg)

I think the problem is in my delegate code as it is setting self.window?.rootViewController to the SwipViewController. Getting rid of that assignment makes the Tab Bar show back up, but it is black inside of the Home tab so it is still not working.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)

    let navigationController = SecondViewController(rootViewController: pageController)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

I also tried getting the corresponding window for the "Home" tab from the storyboard and setting the navigation controller to that.

```
  let secondViewControllerWindow = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home").view.window
    secondViewControllerWindow?.rootViewController = navigationController
    secondViewControllerWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

But Home is still empty. Here is the ViewController code that is represented by the Home tab and should control the SwipViewController

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: SwipeViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let stb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let page_one = stb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nba") as UIViewController
    let page_two = stb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mlb") as UIViewController
    setViewControllerArray([page_one, page_two])

    page_one.title = "NBA"
    page_two.title = "MLB"

    setFirstViewController(0)

    equalSpaces = true

    //setButtons(UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18), color: UIColor.blackColor())
    //setSelectionBar(80, height: 3, color: UIColor.blackColor())

    setButtonsOffset(40, bottomOffset: 5)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

My questions is similar to these other questions but I did not find an answer.

[Using Page View Controller inside Tab Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31695340/using-page-view-controller-inside-tab-swift)

[Xcode 6 - Swift - Custom Tabbar with Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264464/xcode-6-swift-custom-tabbar-with-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem recently, and I found the solution here.
https://github.com/fortmarek/SwipeViewController/issues/26

I didn't put the code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
I tried to work on main.storyboard.

I dragged a PageViewController in and set it as your(SecondViewController)'s RootView.
It worked for me.